# In Android Studio, method comments not showing in intellisense

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellisense

I am developing Android application using Android Studio IDE and I can't find any public API comments in IntelliSense list. Do I need to install some plugins?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File -> Preferences -> Editor and check "Show quick doc on mouse move".

Also make sure the option "Autopopup documentation in (ms):" is checked under: "Code Completion"

Comment: File -> Settings-> Editor -> General and check "Show quick documentation on mouse mouve"